# Error when trying to select menu with Selenium-Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My Selenium IDE recording on Chrome that opens a URL and then do click on a dropdown menu that seems to generate some code dinamically shows 3 actions,
Open, Click, and Mouse Over commands. It works and the id, cpath, css_selector stored by Selenium IDE are shown below.

```
{
"id": "5f885ad3-990a-4989-9382-2572b2",
"version": "2.0",
"name": "Test",
"url": "https://example.com",
"tests": [{
    "id": "00fe2ec5-3529-44ef-9367-b5a7fbf",
    "name": "Test",
    "commands": [{
    "id": "c174b4f2-3a55-4f41-954c-22a8e04",
    "comment": "",
    "command": "open",
    "target": "https://example.com",
    "targets": [],
    "value": ""
    }, {
    "id": "763f8999-7973-48fb-864a-fb3965369021",
    "comment": "",
    "command": "click",
    "target": "css=.blue > .fa",
    "targets": [
        ["css=.blue > .fa", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=//li[@id='MyMenu']/div/button/span[2]", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=//li[3]/div/button/span[2]", "xpath:position"]
    ],
    "value": ""
    }, {
    "id": "3c91c590-94a2-44b8-8d17-bb04d3",
    "comment": "",
    "command": "mouseOver",
    "target": "id=myid",
    "targets": [
        ["id=myid", "id"],
        ["css=#myid", "css:finder"],
        ["xpath=//span[@id='myid']", "xpath:attributes"],
        ["xpath=//li[@id='MyMenu']/div/button/span", "xpath:idRelative"],
        ["xpath=//li[3]/div/button/span", "xpath:position"],
        ["xpath=//span[contains(.,'ABC Banner')]", "xpath:innerText"]
    ],
    "value": ""
    }]
}],

}
```

I've tried the following code in order to reproduce the open menu action but doesn't work

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import gmtime, strftime
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\crd\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get ("https://example.com")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
abc = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*...")))

actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
actionChains.double_click(abc).perform()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='....']").click()

driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".blue > .fa").click()  ##### Before actionChains1  

actionChains1 = ActionChains(driver)     ### Added new actionChains1
element = driver.find_element_by_id("myid")
actionChains1.move_to_element(element).perform();
```

I get this error of no such element like the element is not visible, but actually is visible and website has already loaded completely:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53407/devtools/browser/e4e2207c-bdd6-4754-867c-7b488
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Script.py", line 49, in <module>
    element=driver.find_element_by_id("myid")
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"myid"}
(Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
(Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
```

How to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @supputuri help my issue was fixed. The problem was the page where I was working is a second one that is opened after a login page, then when the new tab was opened, the driver was seeing the first page and the element I was trying to click didn't exist in that page and due to that it was not found.

The line that fixed the issue was adding a switch of window to new page

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

Comment: The web page source would be helpful to understand what data you have in selenium

Comment: @iNoob I've attached below `UPDATE` in my original question the code related with the button for which I want to do click. I see many `id's`in source code appears as type="hidden".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the below step. After navigating to the url and before  mouse over.

```
driver.get ("https://example.com")

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
abc = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,, ".blue > .fa")))
abc.click()

actionChains = ActionChains(driver)
element = driver.find_element_by_id("myid")
actionChains.move_to_element(element).perform();
```

Comment: I've put the line you suggests below `actionchains` line and I get the same error for CSS_Selector `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".blue > .fa"}`

Comment: It should be  before `actionChains = ActionChains(driver)`

Comment: Please see my updated python code in original post. I already have an actionChains line for another purpose (do a double click) before. So I've defined I new actionChains1 and before that line I put the line you suggested but I get the same error. I cannot put the line `...css_selector(".blue > .fa").click()` before the first actionChains because that is a beggining page and the button I want to select appears after.

Comment: I updated the answer to match with your IDE steps. You should be good now.

Comment: Hi, I've tried as you say and after the line ` wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,, ".blue > .fa")))` I et this error `raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)` and `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:` even when  I change the wait to 100 `WebDriverWait(driver, 100)` and visually the page has already loaded.

Comment: That's weird. Were you able to find the element in the browser using devtools with the same css `.blue > .fa`?

Comment: Apparently, the menu is there in 2nd page. so have to use `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])`.

Comment: Exactly supputuri. The issue was the code behind in one page and jumps to 2nd page. Because of that the element was not being found. Thanks so much for your great support and time!!!